# ExtJS4 tree panel issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3, extjs-mvc

We are using treepanel in our application. It is working fine. But if we select the parent node, then the child nodes in that parent are not selected. How do we select the child nodes when we select the parent node?

Is there any method available in ExtJS4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to respond on the `itemclick` event and select all nodes below the clicked node. If you only want to select the immediate children of the clicked node, exchange `cascadeBy()` with `eachChild()`.

```
tree.on("itemclick", function(view, record) {
    var selModel = tree.getSelectionModel();
    record.cascadeBy(function(r) {
        selModel.select(r, true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ext.tree.View class has a select function.

```
select( Ext.data.Model/Index records, Boolean keepExisting, Boolean suppressEvent )
```

On select you can fetch the underlaying nodes and call this, sending on your selected node's children (their records)

Remember to specify second parameter as false, so you don't end up recursive

Comment: I tried select function.It seems that i am doing wrong some where.Do you have any sample regarding this thing,please send me.